# Resource semaphore query compile waits

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, memory, configuration

We have migrated SQL Server Standard Edition from 2008 R2 to 2014. After the migration, we are seeing a huge amount of blocking, and overall the instance is very slow.

The major wait we are seeing is `Resource_Semaphore_Query_Compile`. Some of the queries are requesting more memory and waiting on compile time.

This new server is a beast, Memory : 1TB and CPU : 2 physical cores with 30 logical processors each (60 total). Since this is Standard Edition, max memory is set to 128GB, and I believe there are some issues with maxdop setting and how SQL Server 2014 is utilizing the processors. Maxdop was set to 4 and we changed it to 2, still no luck.

Regarding the resource semaphore wait types: I updated stats on all databases with full scan. We cannot tune the queries as they are encrypted vendor code which used to perform perfectly well on SQL Server 2008 R2.

I cannot change the database compatibility level. I have enabled soft NUMA nodes on this instance by enabling startup trace flag 8079. It created 4 NUMA nodes (before the change, it was 2 NUMA nodes - I can see that in the SQL Server error log).

We are still seeing the `Resource_Semaphore_Query_Compile` waits. Some of the queries are requesting 24GB of memory.

Answer (score 1):

RESOURCE_SEMAPHORE_QUERY_COMPILE isn't aided by more memory in older versions of SQL Server. Since you're on 2014, you can use [Trace Flag 6498](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3024815/large-query-compilation-waits-on-resource-semaphore-query-compile-in-s) if you're on certain patch levels.

That TF increases the large query compile gateway dependent on the amount of memory in your server.